# Emberjs: creating/removing records from a dependent controller

Tags: model, ember.js, controller, dependencies

I'm building an app where you can keep multiple task-lists with comments for each task item. I can create tasks without problem, but when I try to create/remove a comment, I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'createRecord' of undefined" which seems to imply that I'm not properly accessing the comment model correctly either due to a controller dependency or something with the model relationship.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here are my routes

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('lists');
  this.resource('list' , {path: ':list_id'});
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController : function(){
    this.controllerFor('lists').set('model', this.store.find('list'));
    this.controllerFor('task').set('model' , this.store.find('task'));
    this.controllerFor('comment').set('model' , this.store.find('comment');   
  }
});


App.ListsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model : function(){
  return this.store.find('list'); 
  }
});


App.ListRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model : function(params){
    return this.store.find('list', params.list_id);
  }
});
```

Here's my model hierarchy

```
App.List = DS.Model.extend({
 tasks: DS.hasMany('task', {async : true})
});

App.Task = DS.Model.extend({
 description: DS.attr('string'),
 list: DS.belongsTo('list'),
 comments : DS.hasMany('comment')
});

App.Comment = DS.Model.extend({
 body : DS.attr('string'),
 task : DS.belongsTo('task')
});
```

And here are my controllers (Note, the item Controller is simply there to allow me to edit each individual task, so you can ignore it if you like)

```
App.ListController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
});

App.TaskController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs : ['list'],
  actions : {
    addTask : function(){
      var foo = this.store.createRecord('task', { 
        description : '',
        list : this.get('content.id'),
        comments : []  
      });
      foo.save();
      console.log('Task Created!');
    }
  }
});


App.ItemController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
 //code to edit or remove individual tasks
});


App.CommentController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs : ['task'],
  actions : {
    save: function(newCommentBody) {
      var foo = this.store.createRecord('comment',{ 
        body: newCommentBody,
        task : this.get('content.id')
      });
      task.save();     
      console.log('Comment Created!');
    }  
  }     
});
```

Comment: You're using the old syntax for Ember Data.  Are you intentionally using an old version of Ember Data?

Comment: @jeremy-green, didn't intentionally use old version of Ember Data, is there a new way to do things?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay, DeliciousMe.  Much of the syntax for Ember Data has changed, starting with 1.0.0.beta.1.  You'll probably want to check the TRANSITION document for more info : https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

Here are a few things I can spot right off the bat.

#### Finding records

Old way

```
App.List.find();
```

New way

```
this.store.find('list');
```

or

```
this.store.find('list', someListId);
```

#### Creating records

Old way

```
App.List.createRecord({...});
```

New way

```
this.store.createRecord('list', {...});
```

I hope that helps.  Feel free to post follow up questions.

Comment: alright, I've updated to ember data 1.0 beta, everything works like before, but the original issue remains, creating comments still throwing "Cannot call method 'createRecord' of undefined"

Comment: Did you change your `createRecord` code?  What's the snippet that is throwing the error?

Comment: So I'm actually having a lot of trouble figuring out createRecord in my context.  Since I only have record creation in my controller (not in my router). I'm throwing an error "Unable to find transform for object" and "Cannot call method 'serialize' of undefined"

Comment: In a controller it should still be `this.store.createRecord`.  Can you post the code that's giving you trouble and the stack trace that you're getting?

Comment: Hey Jeremy, I started a new thread because this is actually a new question. You can see it here (I've attached a fiddle): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508364/cannot-createrecord-with-ember-data-1-0-0-beta