# Emberjs: Cannot createRecord with Ember Data 1.0.0 beta

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have an app that keeps multiple task lists.  Each task list has multiple tasks.  Each task has multiple comments.

After updating to the new Ember Data, I had to scrap my record creation code. Currently I have this, which doesn't work. Though it doesn't throw any errors, my model does not seem to be updating.

```
App.TaskController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs : ['list'],
  isEditing : false,
  actions : {
    addTask : function(){
      var foo = this.store.createRecord('task', { 
        description : '',
        list : this.get('content.id'),
        comments : []  
      });
      foo.save();
      console.log('Task Created!');
    },
    edit : function(){
        this.set('isEditing', true);
    },
    doneEditing : function(){
        this.set('isEditing', false);
    }
  }
});
```

Does anyone know how to create a new task (as well as how to create new comments) in this context?

See fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/edchao/W6QWj/

Comment: I'm assuming this is somehow solved with pushObject() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I've answered my own question.  I was missing the pushObject() method.  Here is another way to do things.  Although I'm not sure if it's the best practice since it does throw the error "Assertion failed: You can only add a 'list' record to this relationship "

```
App.ListController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions:{
    addTask : function(){
      var foo = this.store.createRecord('task', { 
        description : '',
        list : this.get('content.id'),
        comments : []  
      });
      this.get('tasks').pushObject(foo);
      foo.save();
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you need pushObject in the list controller.

I would do the addTask like this, now almost every method in ember data return a promise

```
App.TaskController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs : ['list'],
  listController:Ember.computed.alias('controllers.list'),
  isEditing : false,
  actions : {
    addTask : function(){
        var listId = this.get('listController.model.id'),
        list = this,
        store = this.get('store');
        console.log('listId',listId);
        store.find('task').then(function(tasks){
            var newId = tasks.get('lastObject.id') + 1,
            newTask = store.createRecord('task', { 
                id:newId,
                description : '',
                list : listId,
                comments : []  
           });
            newTask.save().then(function(newTaskSaved){
                list.pushObject(newTaskSaved);
                console.log('Task Created!');
            });
        });
    },
    edit : function(){
       this.set('isEditing', true);
    },
    doneEditing : function(){
        this.set('isEditing', false);
    }
  }
});
```

I think seerting id's properly is very important, here with fixtures I do with a find, but with the rest adapter would be the backend who assign the id and set it in the response

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/W6QWj/2/